# How do I add the Gmail app to my sharing options (i.e. from photos)?

Tags: gmail, ios, sharing

I've installed the Gmail app on my iPhone 5s (running iOS 8.x).  However, when I'm done taking a photograph (or directly from within the Photos app), if I choose to share I'm presented with a list of options (Mail, Messages, Facebook, etc.) and the Gmail app isn't one of them.

If I go a step further and click the **More** link to see the list of all apps on the phone for which sharing can be enabled, the Gmail app isn't even in that list (while things like Slack.com and other apps I use are).

I use the stock Mail app for my work (Exchange) account, and I could if I wanted share a photo just fine using this, however I prefer the Gmail app's categories of mail.

Do you know a set of steps that can get the Gmail app to appear in this list of sharing options?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, please advise if you need more details or clarification.

Comment: the coders at GMail need to add it, it's not a user option.

Comment: Wow.. new to iPhone (a week or so) and this blows my mind.  Seems like it would be a fundamental function for an email client. Thanks.

Comment: If Google add it, then it has to go past Apple's reviewers, to check it's as safe as they think it is. Sandboxing is pretty tight under iOS. The feature you want is not impossible, it just needs to be implemented at source, not added by the user. The end result is no-one needs an anti-virus scanner on an iDevice ;-)

Comment: @Tetsujin care to make that a answer ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Guess I could ;)

Comment: Just found that MyMail app does support this, Boxer doesn't. Haven't explored others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coders at Gmail need to add it, it's not a user option, I'm afraid.

If Google add it, then it has to go past Apple's reviewers, to check it's as safe as they think it is.  Sandboxing is pretty tight under iOS.

The feature you want is not impossible, it just needs to be implemented at source, not added by the user.

The end result is no-one needs an anti-virus scanner on an iDevice ;)

Try reporting it on the [Gmail feature requests page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6142372?hl=en)