# How to configure iOS 12 sharesheet to add WhatsApp Messaging?

Tags: ios, sharing, whatsapp.app

Links, Photos, and other data can be shared through options: Messages, Mail, etc.

For example, if I am browsing images in the Photos app, I would like to the ability to click the share button and select WhatsApp from a list of apps, so that the photo can be forwarded to a contact. WhatsApp is not on the list and needs to be added said list and configured to accept photos.

How does one add WhatsApp as an option to the sharing list in all apps?

Comment: Are you talking about through the sharesheet?

Comment: @user9950573 *Great* question: The term [sharesheet](https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/share-sheet-input-types-apd7644168e1/ios) is new to me. Is it available in IOS12 to  configure downloaded apps for photo and other data types?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170058/how-do-i-add-the-gmail-app-to-my-sharing-options-i-e-from-photos?rq=1

Comment: @ankii  Yes,  you are correct.  We can roll-back the question and I pose a separate question if you would like to do that.  I am sensing (but not certain) that only the application developer can add an app to the share list.

Comment: Yeah thanks! Just revisit history if you need specific text/ link.

Answer (score 2):

If the developer didn’t program the hooks to receive a forward, you cannot accomplish this. Contact the developer or choose another app that has that feature.

If the developer enabled this, the mechanics are easy to curate your list of share destinations:

1. Tap share, swipe to the right end and tap “more” for shifting the order of apps, and also enabling/disabling them.
2. Scroll towards the bottom and you'll see all apps that are allowed to use sharesheet.

[image]

It’s possible a third things could happen, which would be corruption of the data store that holds your customizations. I would back up the device and then erase the device and install only WhatsApp to validate. Use the "three bar" icon to shift it in the list. If it doesn't appear, then seek assistance from Apple or hope restoring your full backup allows the addition.

Comment: This is a step in the right direction: is it possible to add an app to the Activities list shown in the screenshot?

Comment: not if the app doesn't support this. Scroll towards the bottom and you'll see all apps that are allowed

Comment: Ankii, is this iOS 12 or iOS 13?

Comment: iOS 12 @nohillside what did I miss ?

Comment: I have iOS 13 here where sharing works a bit different. But the OP is on 12, so all fine.

Comment: @gatorback I see WhatsApp in the screenshot so it should already be there on your phone as well

Comment: @nohillside for the sake of completeness, you may add a screenshot too

Comment: Well, WhatsApp is there by default (apparently in both iOS12 and iOS13) so I'm not sure right now which problem we are solving. And with the question focused on iOS12 the answer is fine as it is.

Comment: I’ve edited this a bit. If WhatsApp allows sharing but not on one specific device, the issue is corruption of the share preferences. Triage for that is erasing after a backup.